# Does webdriver IEserver throttle requests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, throttling

I am experiencing a hang while calling the WebElement.Click() on selenium 2.39 and 2.42 IEDriver, using InternetExplorer. 
I know that click() is a blocking call, but the interesting part is that the first time the call hangs, it block for 5 minutes, the next time a hang happens it lasts 10 minutes, and the third time 30 minutes; and these timing are exact.

Is there any throttling happening between the selenium Webdriver and IEServer? I can't find any documentation pointing out so, and there didn't seem to be anything on the implementation of the methods either. Trying to figure out why the hangs are happening ..

From my logs:
11:12:56.353 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1117 >> "POST /session/58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a/element/098d2220-9493-4d2e-afb9-0730c4659ba1/click HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
 ......
11:12:56.353 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1117 >> "{"id":"098d2220-9493-4d2e-afb9-0730c4659ba1"}"
11:18:15.512 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1117 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"

Notice the difference in time between request and response.

the next time a hang happens:

11:18:17.241 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1139 >> "{"id":"a42ee6c9-fd3c-4b44-bfc5-ebccb7211a80"}"
11:28:55.706 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1139 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"

11:18:17.241 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1139 >> "{"id":"a42ee6c9-fd3c-4b44-bfc5-ebccb7211a80"}"
11:28:55.706 [org.apache.http.wire][Forwarding clickElement on session 58c0dfc6-eb38-4b0e-a4df-7a4b46c73f6a to remote] DEBUG - http-outgoing-1139 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"

And the next time is 30 minutes. 
This is all apache logging inside calls to selenium webElement.click();

I am running a proxy to capture and display all network trace in parralel with the test runs, and there are no actual http calls pending between my machine and the server from where the web page is being loaded.

Comment: please post relevent code if possible

Comment: I added the log output, and code if very typical create a WebElement, and click on it: <br>WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(xpath);<br>webElement.click(); All the wait happens arount the click(). Breakpoint before and after, and from looking at the apache logs of the json communication, it seems like the webdriver client part is waiting on the server response.